# Python How to sleep until a specific timestamp "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS"

Tags: python, timestamp, sleep

So I have the following timestamp:
`23-03-2023 10:11:00`

How is it possible in python to sleep from the current time until the timestamp while printing the remaining time in hours-minutes-seconds?

I don't get quiet the logic of all the different timestamp formats.

I have seen several threads where just a simple time delta gets calculated but my intuition tells me that this is not the right way.

like this:

```
t1 = datetime.datetime.now()

# other stuff here
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = t2 - t1
if delta.seconds > WAIT:
    # do stuff
else:
    # sleep for a bit
```

Maybe you guys have any ideas.

Comment: If your program is printing then it's not sleeping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try subtracting the dates (but check that it's not negative), then using the `.total_seconds()` function to get the time difference in seconds:

```
import time
import datetime


def sleepUntil(t2):
    t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    if t1 > t2:
        return
    td = t2 - t1
    for i in range(int(td.total_seconds()), 0, -1):
        print(f'{i//3600} hours, {(i//60)%60} minutes, and {i%60} seconds')
        time.sleep(1)


sleepUntil(datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 13, 9, 27, 50))
```

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, then you can mark it as correct to indicate that it helped you. This would help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Comment: it didn't really solved my issue as I wanted to input the specific timestamp and get a print of time amount left until the date is reached

Comment: @realsuspection I've edited my answer to include a countdown-like version too. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Its better now but not perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is that you're trying to develop some kind of countdown timer where the "timeout" date/time is expressed as a string. If so, you could try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

CSI = '\x1B['

def wait_until(timestamp):
    until = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    print(f'{CSI}?25l', end='') # hide cursor
    while (now := datetime.now()) < until:
        dt = datetime.fromtimestamp((until - now).seconds-3600)
        ft = datetime.strftime(dt, '%H:%M:%S')
        print(f'{ft}\r', end='')
        sleep(1)
    print(f'{CSI}?25h') # show cursor

wait_until('12-03-2023 15:33:55')
```